# CTest build ID not set

Tags: ctest, cdash

I have a CDash configured to accept posts for automatic builds and tests. However, when any system attempts to post results to the CDash, the following error is produced. The result is that each result gets posted four times (presumably the original posting attempt plus the three retries).

Can anyone give me a hint as to what sets this mysterious build ID? I found some [code](https://www.kitware.com/svn/CDash/Release-1-6/models/build.php) that seems to produce a similar error, but still no lead on what might be happening.

> Build::GetNumberOfErrors(): BuildId not set
>     Build::GetNumberOfWarnings(): BuildId not set
>      Submit failed, waiting 5 seconds...
>      Retry submission: Attempt 1 of 3
>      Server Response:

Answer (score 1):

The buildid for CDash is computed based on the site name, the build name and the build stamp of the submission. You should have a **Build.xml** file in a Testing/20110311-* directory in your build tree. Open that up and see if any of those fields (near the top) is empty. If so, you need to set BUILDNAME and SITE with -D args when configuring with CMake. Or, set CTEST_BUILD_NAME and CTEST_SITE in your ctest -S script.

If that's not it, then this is a mystery. I've not seen this error occur before...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue though Site and Buildname are available in test.xml and are visible on cdash (4 times).  I can see the jobs increment by refreshing between retries so it seems that the submission succeeds and reports a timeout.

Update: This seems to have started when I added the -j(nprocs) switch to the ctest command.  changing CtestSubmitRetryDelay: 20 (was 5) allowed a server response through that indicates the cdash version may not be able to handle the multi-proc option I'll have to look into that for my issue.  Perhaps setting CtestSubmitRetryDelay to a larger number will get you back a server response as it did for me.  g'luck!

Out of range value for column 'processorclockfrequency'